# How to keep checkBox selection in Primefaces DataTable with pagination to use in JQuery function?

Tags: jquery, primefaces, datatable

I got a bug to fix and I am confused, we have a page that may open a dialog with a Primefaces  multi-selection Datatable, after the user have selected the values he wants there is an "ok" button that converts the literal values to tags and put them all in a Primefaces text editor component. The problem is that when the pagination happens the selection from the previous page is lost.

I've already worked with multi-selection in Datatable but in this specific case, due to Jquery function that do all the process to put the tags in the text editor we are not using the multi-selection as Primefaces showcase suggests. Therefor the list pointed in "selection" Datatable's atribute is never setted.

I think I have to find a way to keep the selection using JQuery but I'm not good at it so I'm here asking your help.

Here it goes the relevant code related:

```
<p:dataTable id="tagsTable" var="tag"
  value="#{MB.tagList}" rowKey="#{tag.tag.id}"
  rows="10" selection="#{MB.tagsSelected}"
  rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10" paginator="true">

   <p:column style="width:50px; white-space: pre-wrap;">
   <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="tagCheckbox" value="#{tag.checked}" />
   <input type="hidden" id="tagHidden" value="#{tag.tag.tag}" />
  </p:column>
```

And here the function:

```
        <script>
            function useTags(){
                var checks = $( "#formTag\\:tagsTable input:checked" );
                if (checks.length == 0 ) {
                    alert('Show MSG...');
                    return;
                }
                $.each(checks , function( key, value ) {
                    var $div = $(value).parent().parent().parent(); 
                    var stringToInsert = '<input type="button" value="' + $div.find('input')[1].value + '" disabled="disabled"/>';
                    $('#mainForm\\:editor_input').cleditor()[0].execCommand('inserthtml',stringToInsert);
                });
                dlgSearchTag.hide();
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: You can capture the onchange event when the checkbox is checked and add the contents of the "value" attribute to an array variable. But if it is unchecked you delete the element from array. This way, always you have the elements marked into an array element.

Comment: Thx for trying to help. I did as you said, I can keep the selection if I remove the "selection" parameter from the Datatable therefor it will not reset it to null when the pagination occurs. But this didn't solve the problem, now I have the complete list on the MB side but the selection list Jquery function uses still is empty when the pagination occurs. I could try to make the function job in the MB with Java but I don't know if it is possible, any more hints?